# Why does the gradle wrapper need a specific setting to enable code completion?

Tags: gradle

If I simply import a gradle project (without wrapper) into IntelliJ IDEA, code completion works fine. The docs for the wrapper say:

> use the -all distribution to enable your IDE to enable code-completion

Why is this necessary?

NB The gradle wrapper directory is checked into source control, so it presumably doesn't change frequently...  but that in turn means that it can't be storing some kind of index of  your source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about your source code but about Gradle source code.

The [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper) says :

> Let’s assume the following use case to illustrate the use of the
>   command line options. You would like to generate the Wrapper with
>   version 4.0 and use the -all distribution to enable your IDE to enable
>   code-completion and being able to navigate to the **Gradle source code**

The code completion concerns only Gradle files